# Entity Framework 6 (ASP .NET MVC) blocks the entire application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, error-handling

when an error is thrown by entity framework (ie. max length not respected), every single call to *SaveChanges()* generates the old error message, not allowing to perform correctly the new sql query.

Every user is touched and a reload of the application is needed!

What do I miss?

Here some code :

```
        Society _new = new Society ()
        {
            Nom = "TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST", // MAX LENGTH 10
            Adresse = "45,  rue Paris",                
            ....                
        };

        try
        {
            context.Society.Add(_new);
            context.SaveChanges(); 
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {                
            //handle error
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //handle error
        }
```

After the error is cought, every single time I call *context.SaveChanges();* (even for other objects) Entity generates the same errors, like if the context be stuck.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have added incorrect object to context and event after catching errors this object is still there in the context so on the next invoke of SaveChanges() error appears too

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact that I was using always the same DbContext.

In that way (therefore, never calling the method *.Dispose()* ) the error blocked the only context I used.

> A service method must use the same DbContext instance throughout the
>   duration of a *business transaction*. This is so that all the changes
>   made to your persistent model are tracked and either committed to the
>   underlying data store or rolled back in an atomic manner.

For more information: http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/